# Stop git looking at a directory

Tags: git

I want to stop git monitoring a directory so if I'm in that directory and type `git status` I get the message, `fatal: not a git repository`.
Currently when I type `git status`, I get `On branch master`.

I've tried `git rm -r --cached <filename>` but get the message, `fatal: not a git repository` appears.

I'm quite new to this and so I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you asking how to stop git tracking a subdirectory within a repository?

Comment: @CalumHalpin I doubt it is, but if the answer to your question is yes, then perhaps this question should be modified and re-opened. (And perhaps answered with, "you can't", I think.)

Answer (score 1):

Git is not tracking all the directories in your machine.

When you type `git status` in a directory, you are calling the program git and it simply return `fatal: not a git repository` because that directory is not a repository (it doesn't have `.git` directory). It is the normal behaviour. It's like run python with a file that hasn't a valid python language format.

Answer (score 0):

The premise of the question that git looks at all the directories is wrong.

Git commands such as `git status` work only in the directories where git has been initialized. Usually, you will find a folder like `.git` at the root of the directory where git is initialized.

E.g. lets say `/usr/a/d1` where git is initialized. Then in the directory  `/usr/a/d1` and its subdirectory git status will not return `fatal: not a git repository`

Say `/usr/a/d2` is a directory that is NOT initialized with git then in the directory `/usr/a/d2` and in its subdirectory you will get `fatal: not a git repository`